# Python: Google Spread Sheet API: How to design storing users data in Google Sheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Making a small Python web app to allow users to login and store data. Relatively small user group of about ~500-1k, so I've decided to keep it simple and use google sheet as the database. This way I would avoid maintaining a database/server

I initially thought each sheet(give it a unique id) would serve as one user's database where I can store the data but came to know Google Sheet has a 200 sheet per spread limitation.

What would your advice be to design and store each user's unique data in a Google Spread Sheet using the [api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) (or other proper databases). Firebase makes it easy for you to authenticate with [Firebase login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). You'll also be able to add more features later when you scale.

Spreadsheets are not meant as databases. Save yourself future troubles and brickwalls. It's also limiting. Be kind to yourself and to the people you'll be bugging later on when you run to problems.